# Retrieving JSON key using only the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

In a variable I have the value of a key in an JSON object. Picture if you will ...

```
var stooges = [
    {"id" : "a", "name" : "Moe"},
    {"id" : "b", "name" : "Larry"},
    {"id" : "c", "name" : "Shemp"}
];

var stooge = "Larry";
```

I should like to know how I can retrieve the key (in this case "b") from the JSON object.

Thank you kindly in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var id;
$.each(stooges, function(_, obj){
    if(obj.name == 'Larry'){
        id = obj.id;
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. This was successful in helping me. Sadly I do not have a high enough reputation point to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the collection:

```
var find = 'Larry';

var result = stooges.filter(function(stooge) {
  return stooge.name = find;
}).pop();

console.log(result); //=> {id: 'b', name: 'Larry'}
```